material-calendarview dependency is not working
so i want to use the Calendar view from the Library, no matter how i try to import it it always returns the same error i tried different versions but i always get the same error: Duplicate class android.support.......... , to my understanding this means that it uses a com.android.support Library instead of an androidx Library, but how and why and what version to use to resolve this i cant find out im realy new to this and realy irritated thanks for the help in advance, here is the code:
settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "fungus"
include ':app'

build.gradle:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.guolindev.permissionx:permissionx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.8'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.1'  // Update version as needed
    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.1' // version 1.4.3 for example downloads but does not work because of the same error.
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

i hope this is all the relevant code
